# Node that depends on the particular values of it's parents in a Bayesian network?

Tags: bayesian-network

Consider a Bayesian network containing a binary variable C which denotes whether a certain person has a child or not. There is a second variable B which denotes the birthdate of the person's youngest child. There is an edge from C to B, but not always. Indeed, B is only meaningful where C=1. Or to put in other words, in p(B|C), C should automatically be set to 1. P(B|C=0), if it were meaningful, would have to be 0 everywheren! How can one model this situation in a Bayesian network?

Answer (score 0):

the network graph should not change, so there should always be a connection between C and B.

I would suggest to add it into the possible options for B:

usually B has 365 options, (days of the year) so lets add an option of "wasnt born" and have 366 options. so:

`P(B="wasnt born" | C=1) = 0`

`P(B="wasnt born" | C=0) = 1`

`P(B="1/1/2021" | C=1) = 1/365` (or some other probability)

good luck!